# Javascript for loop stops unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this function which has to remove an object from firebase firestore database and also should remove the id of this object from the users which this object belongs to. I am using double for loop to check all of this and removing the id's from user when it is the object id. But as long as this condition is true for loop stops execution immediately. Here is the function structure :

```
removeObj(obj) {

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.users.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < obj.users[i].objects.length; j++) {

      //WHEN THIS CONDITION IS TRUE LOOP STOPS EXECUTION
      if (obj.id == obj.users[i].objects[j]) {
        //this scope never gets executed although the condition is true. 
        console.log("if is true");
        obj.users[i].objects.splice(j, 1);
      } else {
        console.log('object id : ', obj.users[i].objects[j])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in the code above, when the if statement should evaluate to true, the second for loop execution stops(didn't check for the first one). Everything goes fine is the statement is false tho. But the moment it is true loop stops. I tried with triple and double equals sign. same behavior. I also tried with foreach same behavior.

No idea what is going on. Thanks In advance!

obj structure in this example :

```
obj = {
   id : "abcd",
   users : [
     {
        id : "aqwuiop",
        objects : [
           "tyui",
           "kjhg",
           "uhbg",
           "abcd",
           "fghj"
        ]
     },
     {...}
   ]
}
```

So  what happens is I see this first 3 element of the objects array of the user in log that comes from else scope but in the forth element(which is the one that if should evaluate to true) I don't see it in the log coming from else scope of course but I also don't see the log in the if scope. And fifth element log also doesn't appear and rest of the function gets executed.

Comment: You need to loop backwards

Comment: @NikKyriakides what do you mean? lol

Comment: what he means is that you are looping on index 5, you eliminate index 5, now 6 is 5, and 7 is 6, and so on. Make sense?

Comment: @AkilDemir When removing elements from an array, you should iterate starting from the last element going towards the first.

Comment: Guys what is happening is I can't remove any item from the array(I want to but code doesn't get executed). So I don't delete anything from the array already. So after running this code over an abject doesn't already change anything?

Comment: If none of the loops are entered then the problem is somewhere else and you need to post an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/1814486) for someone to help you.

Comment: You're attempting to iterate over and destructively modify an array at the same time. Rather than deleting elements as you iterate, perhaps try to work on a new array, pushing elements which you want to keep while skipping the elements you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop in reverse/backwards.

As mentioned in the comments, when you remove an element from an array, the array itself gets reindexed so the `.length` in the `for` condition is no longer valid.

Here's an example of a reverse loop with a [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

// iterate from the last element towards the first.
for (let i = numbers.length; i > 0; i--) {
  // remove all even numbers, i.e the ones perfectly divisible by 2.
  if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
    numbers.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Oh I got your point. I will change that but the main problem is I am already not able to remove any item from the array because the code doesn't executed. As I commented in my code example, execution doesn't enter the inside the if statement. So I didn't already removed anything. When I log the user back, I see that noting has been changed.

Comment: Please read my comments on your question. You didn't post a sample of your data so none can actually run the code and find out what the problem is. If the loop containing the `.splice` call isn't actually entered then your problem is somewhere else but without an MCVE it's impossible to know where.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're operating on the object over which the for-loop is iterating, this can result in the loop getting cut short.

Specifically, the line `obj.users[i].objects.splice(j, 1);` is likely causing unexpected behavior.

The splice array method operates destructively, changing the contents of the array on which the for loop operates.

It may be easier to keep track of logic if, rather than iterating over and destructively operating on the array at the same time, you perform your `if` check on the original array, then copy passing elements over to a new array.

Comment: I had a console.log above this `splice` method and it didn't work too. So execution doesn't enter the if statement.

Comment: If execution doesn't enter the if statement, this is because your if statement is always returning `false`. Without knowing the nature of the data you're using, it is impossible to tell you why this is the case.

Comment: I thought what you said too that is why I have a log in the else statement but it doesn't log it. I edited my post. Please check.